# NMAP Unknown Device Found on Network

Tags: networking, nmap

I run pfSense, and my network is 192.168.1.1/24. pfSense provides the DNS. I have OpenVPN setup using 10.0.0.0/24. I only have one device that uses OpenVPN, and that device is not connected. Something made me aware that there is something at 10.55.1.142. I'm embarrassed that I don't remember what it was.

When I run nmap 10.55.1.142, I get

```
"Host seems down.",
```

but when I run "nmap -Pn 10.55.1.142", I get

```
Nmap scan report for 10.55.1.142 Host is up (0.0051s latency). Not shown: 999 filtered ports PORT STATE SERVICE 53/tcp open domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.89 seconds
```

arp -a 10.55.1.142 reports:

```
arp: in 15 entries no match found.
```

ping 10.55.1.142 reports:

```
PING 10.55.1.142 (10.55.1.142) 56(84) bytes of data. From 10.240.177.137 icmp_seq=7 Packet filtered From 10.240.177.137 icmp_seq=12 Packet filtered From 10.240.177.137 icmp_seq=15 Packet filtered
```

Is there a way to find out what the device is? Is there a way to keep it off my network? Should I be concerned?

Comment: You haven't show any evidence that that host is on your LAN, other than the fact that its address is not publicly routable. Look at your route table to see how you are reaching it. Also run a traceroute. ISPs use RFC1918 private IP addresses on their internal networks. These addresses are routable within a private network like your ISP's network. Your router at the head of your home network just routes everything to your ISP, thus you can reach "private" IP addresses being used on your ISP's network. This could be something like a DNS server at your ISP.

Comment: Further to @spiff comment - if the devices are on your network (more technically segment) they will have arp entries when scsnned - which will provide MAC addresses.  The first 3 parts of a MAC can be looked up and can give a clue of the devices manufacturer.